# How to force this content to fit to the view on android devices using Ionic 4?

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

Solution (kind of) -> I ended up just putting mode="ios" on all of the segments/buttons/tabs and they fit on the screen, they just don't have the material design style.

I have an ion-segment and ion-tab-bar which look fantastic on iOS, but on android they simply don't fit within the view and are cut off because they are extending beyond it.

I can provide some picture showing the exact problem I'm having: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO19O.jpg. I've tried setting CSS properties just to try and get it to fit inside and nothing seems to work, I've also tried just setting the mode for the segment button to iOS but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
<app-header></app-header>

<ion-content>

    <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
        <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="md-refresh"    refreshingSpinner="crescent" color="primary" disabled="false"
                           pullingText="Pull to refresh"  refreshingText="Refreshing..."></ion-refresher-content>
    </ion-refresher>

    <ion-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" color="secondary" type="indeterminate"></ion-progress-bar>

    <ion-searchbar animated="true" placeholder="Search" [showCancelButton]="false" [(ngModel)]="searchFilter"></ion-searchbar>

    <ion-segment color="dark" [(ngModel)]="leaderboardType">
        <ion-segment-button value="commuter">Commuter</ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="business">Business</ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <ion-segment color="primary" value="0" [(ngModel)]="commuteFilter">
        <ion-segment-button value="0">
            <ion-icon name="md-infinite"></ion-icon>
            All
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let method of commuteMethods" value='{{method.id}}'>
            <ion-icon name="{{method.icon}}"></ion-icon>
            {{method.name}}
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <app-commuter-leaderboards *ngIf="leaderboardType === 'commuter' && users" [users]="users" [commuteFilter]="commuteFilter" [commuteYear]="commuteYear" [searchFilter]="searchFilter"></app-commuter-leaderboards>

    <app-business-leaderboards *ngIf="leaderboardType === 'business' && users" [users]="users" [commuteFilter]="commuteFilter" [commuteYear]="commuteYear" [searchFilter]="searchFilter"></app-business-leaderboards>

</ion-content>
```

And here's the ion tabs page

```
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" color="primary" mode="ios">
    <ion-tab-button tab="activities">
      <ion-icon name="md-globe"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>News Feed</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="leaderboards">
      <ion-icon name="md-podium"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Leaderboards</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button (click)="openCommuteEntryDialog()">
      <ion-icon name="md-add-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Log Commute</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="users/{{currentUser.id}}">
      <ion-icon name="md-contact"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Profile</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="information">
      <ion-icon name="md-information-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Information</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

And finally the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Smart Commute Emmet</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting that when you load the ionic app on an android phone, using the chrome browser, it should display the entire ion-segment and tab-bar and not allow it to go beyond the screen.

Comment: whats is your index.html and meta tags?

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: I have the same issue on android